# Nginx + Wordpress Multisite 3.4.2 + subdirectories + static pages and permalinks

Tags: nginx, wordpress-mu

I am trying to setup Wordpress Multisite, using subdirectories, with Nginx, php5-fpm, APC, and Batcache.
As many other people, I am getting stuck in the rewrite rules for permalinks.

I have followed these two guides, which seem to be as official as you can get:
http://evansolomon.me/notes/faster-wordpress-multisite-nginx-batcache/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_Subdirectory_rules

It is partially working:

- http://blog.ssis.edu.vn works.
- http://blog.ssis.edu.vn/umasse/ works.

But other permalinks, like these two to a post or to a static page, don't work:

- http://blog.ssis.edu.vn/umasse/2008/12/12/hello-world-2/
- http://blog.ssis.edu.vn/umasse/sample-page/

They either take you to a 404 error, or to some other blog!

Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  blog.ssis.edu.vn;
    root         /var/www;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/blog-access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/blog-error.log;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    # Add trailing slash to */username requests
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    # Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 24h;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # this prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
      location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

    # Pass uploaded files to wp-includes/ms-files.php.
    rewrite /files/$ /index.php last;

    if ($uri !~ wp-content/plugins) {
        rewrite /files/(.+)$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
    }

    # Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
    if (!-e $request_filename) {

        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+.*(/wp-admin/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    # Forbid PHP on upload dirs
        if ($uri ~ "uploads") {
            return 403;
        }

        client_max_body_size 25M;
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Any ideas are welcome! Have I done something wrong?
I have disabled Batcache to see if it makes any difference, but still no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It wasn't the rewrite rules, though Michael Hampton definitely set me in the right direction.

For some reason, the wp-config.php file had two very important lines for Multisite configuration commented out: PATH_CURRENT_SITE and BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE.

As soon as I fixed that, everything started working perfectly, and our site is now blazing fast.
I guess the real question is: how the h*** did this work all this time?

That's it here. Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you've got a real mess on your hands.

Overall the nginx configuration looks good. The only thing that struck me on first reading as being possibly "wrong" was the `try_files` statement. In my production WordPress multisite, I have:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
```

It's not necessary to append the args, as WordPress picks them up from `REQUEST_URI` when it is available, (almost always) and `PATH_INFO` when they aren't present in the query string.

Yes, I'm aware that the statement you are using is what's "recommended" on the WordPress site. Of course it's also a wiki that anybody can edit, so it has to be taken with a grain of salt, just like Wikipedia.

Comment: It seems my fastcgi_params file is incomplete, because there is no reference to PATH_INFO.
Can you share your fastcgi_params?

Comment: Sorry, old Apache-isms surfacing in my brain when I wrote that. PATH_INFO isn't defined by default in nginx; you would have to [explicitly define it](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_split_path_info). This isn't necessary for WordPress since it will receive the original `REQUEST_URI` anyway and use that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Well, it seems to have made some difference: I removed Batcache and the APC object cache from the equation. I also added fastcgi_split_path_info and additional fastcgi_params (including PATH_INFO) from here: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_split_path_info
And now things are working! Now I need to look into getting back some of that speed boost that I was getting from Batcache and APC...

Comment: Ok, I just readded the APC object cache, and it's clear that this is what is causing the problems. There is definitely a key clash happening, with individual blogs overwriting each other's objects.

Comment: I found the ultimate solution, and it was, of course, a PEBKAC... See my own answer. Thanks in any case for your help! It did eventually send me in the correct path.